# Is every finitely dimensional basic $K$-algebra isomorphic to a bound quiver algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quiver

Given a positive integer $n$, how to classify $n$-dimensional basic $K$-algebras?, where $K$ is algebraically closed.

For $n=3$, Let $A=\left[
                       \begin{array}{ccc}
                         K &0& 0\\
                         0& K& 0\\
                         0 &0& K \\
                       \end{array}
                     \right]
,B=\left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
       K & 0 \\
       K & K\\
     \end{array}
   \right]$ and $ C=\left[
                       \begin{array}{ccc}
                         K &0& 0\\
                         K&0& 0\\
                         K &0& 0\\
                       \end{array}
                     \right]
$. Then we have $\operatorname{rad}A=\left[
                       \begin{array}{ccc}
                         0 &0& 0\\
                         0& 0& 0\\
                         0 &0& 0 \\
                       \end{array}
                     \right]
,\operatorname{rad}B=\left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & 0 \\
       K & 0\\
     \end{array}
   \right]$ and $ \operatorname{rad}C=\left[
                       \begin{array}{ccc}
                         0 &0& 0\\
                         K&0& 0\\
                         K &0& 0\\
                       \end{array}
                     \right]
$, and hence $A/\operatorname{rad}A\cong K\times K\times K, B/\operatorname{rad}B\cong K\times K, C/\operatorname{rad}C\cong K$, this implies that $A,B$ and $C$ are basic three-dimensional algebras.  Let $ Q$ is the quiver

$$\circlearrowright^{\beta} $$
and $\mathcal{I}$ is the ideal of$ KQ$ generated by one zero relation $ \beta^3$. Then $D=KQ/I$ is basic,  Are there other three dimensional basic algebra which are not isormorphic to the above? It is known that every bound quver algebra is basic, conversely, Is every  $n$-dimensional basic $K$-algebra isomorphic to a bound quiver algebra?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Structure_coefficients

Comment: In principle you could write down all quivers with number of vertices + number of arrows $\leq n$. Then try to write down all relations making it an $n$-dimensional algebra. This could be done with some effort, as long as $n$ is not too big. But the reallly hard task is to decide whether two such algebras are isomorphic. I doubt there is an easy receipe unless $n$ is really small, maybe $\leq 10$.

Comment: What is a “basic” algebra?

Comment: Assume that $A$ is a $K$-algebra with a complete set
${e_1,\cdots , e_n}$ of primitive orthogonal idempotents. The algebra $A$ is called
basic if $e_iA \ncong e_jA$, for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: @AiminXu There is one more $3$-dimensional algebra: There are two algebras with $C/\operatorname{rad} C\cong K$, one has $\operatorname{rad}^2 C=0$, another one has $\operatorname{rad}^2 C\cong \operatorname{rad} C\cong K$.

Comment: If a finite dimensional algebra $C$ with $C/radC\cong K$ and $rad^2C\cong radC\cong K$, then $C$ is two-dimensional.

Comment: @AiminXu Oh, sorry I meant $C/\operatorname{rad} C\cong K$, $\operatorname{rad} C/\operatorname{rad}^2 C\cong K$ and $\operatorname{rad}^2 C\cong K$, $\operatorname{rad}^3 C=0$.

Answer (score 3):

> Is every n-dimensional basic K-algebra isomorphic to a bound quiver algebra?

Yes, over algebraically closed field every basic algebra isomorphic to a quiver algebra with relations. You can find proof of this fact in the book Auslander, Reiten, Smalo Representation theory of Artin algebras p.65.

Comment: This is in fact proved in pretty much every textbook which deals with the subject!

Comment: Let $A$ be a basic and connected finite dimensional Kalgebra, then it is isomorphic to a bound quiver algebra by Theorem 3.7 p64, ( I. Assem, D. Simson and A. Skowro$\acute{n}$ski,  Elements of the Representation Theory
of Associative Algebras, Volume 1)